# How to keep settings if app was reinstalled

Tags: ios, ios-settings-bundle

If application has been reinstalled through xcode all kept settings are cleaned. How to avoid such behaviour?

More detailed: An app has been installed, then I made changes in settings ( settings bundle) and they were stored. After I reinstalled the application through xcode (I didn't remove the app) and all my settings have been cleaned that I made before . I would like to keep my settings after installing application or perhaps there is another way to keep settings of app after installing of it.

Example:

1. I created Settings Bundle ( File -> New -> File -> Resourses -> Settings bundle)
2. Changed Root.plist and added there new dict for address value. See below.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>StringsTable</key>
   <string>Root</string>
   <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>Type</key>
           <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
           <key>Title</key>
           <string>Server</string>
       </dict>
       <dict>
           <key>Type</key>
           <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
           <key>Title</key>
           <string>Address</string>
           <key>Key</key>
           <string>server_address_preference</string>
           <key>KeyboardType</key>
           <string>Alphabet</string>
           <key>IsSecure</key>
           <false/>
           <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
           <string>None</string>
           <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
           <string>No</string>
       </dict>
   </array>
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by reinstall the app through Xcode ?

Comment: Yep! Reinstalling the app through XCode

Comment: But what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I am new in ios, I moved from android developing, and android keeps settings if app was reinstalled through Android Studio or Play Market, but ios cleans all my stored settings but I would like to hold settings if the application was reinstalled

Comment: Can you share an example of a setting you are speaking about ?

Comment: Ok.  I not understand why do you need my sample but see updated  description!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the settings of your app use `UserDefaults`, it's the same concept as `SharedPreferences` in Android development. So, you can store there user related settings as well as everything else which should remain untouched after updating (Xcode reinstallation) of the app.

[UserDefaults Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

**Example of usage.**

Setting value:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "someValue")
```

Retrieving value:

```
let boolValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "someValue")
```